# Excel function IFERROR(value, value_if_error). Does it have a python equivalent?

Tags: python, pandas

Does python have a function similar to the excel function IFERROR(value, value_if_error)

Can I use np.where?

Many Thanks

Comment: No, a function like that doesn't make any sense outside of Excel. What are you planning to do with that function? You should ask about your actual problem instead of what you think is a solution. Please read [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On large amount of data, you'll probably want to condition element-wise using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1,1])
cond_values = np.array(['error','good'])
b = cond_values[(a>5).astype(int)]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
['error' 'error' 'error' 'error' 'error' 'good' 'good' 'error' 'error' 'error']
```

**EDIT**:
If you are using a pandas.Dataframe to store your data, which is the closest to excel type of structure, then you can use `df.fillna`. See docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Answer (score 1):

No sure what you mean by an error in data in Python.

Do you mean NA? Then try the `fillna` function in pandas.

Comment: yes I mean NA . If it is the case then I would like to change that say to zero.

Comment: @SBad Please be more specific about the problem. Can you give an example for data and errors?

Comment: @SBad, see the documentation here. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: @mr_mo  i dont have a specific example. I was trying to replicate an excel process which uses iferror function. Thats why i asked whether there was any function doing similar thing. Note the iferror function in excel is mean to replace the error with zero. Depending on the data, the error would be either a NA or a missing number

Comment: @SBad well that depends on your pythonic data structure. Please see edit.